# How to update a nested object in array that is in the array of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have Locations collection in MongoDB that includes two documents.
Each one of them has its own array of confirmed bookings as objects with Ids.
How can I update the object that has _id: c1?
Is it possible to do that in a single query?

```
[{
_id :63233022222222,
title :"Ravenholm",
price: 180,
capacity: 2,
confirmedBookings: [
 {
  _id : r1,
  start: 1663207200000,
  finish: 1663210799999
 },
 {
  _id: r2,
  start: 1663322400000,
  finish: 1663329599999
 }
]
},
{
_id :6323301111111111,
title :"City 17",
price: 360,
capacity: 4,
confirmedBookings: [
 {
  _id : c1,
  start: 1663207200000,
  finish: 1663210799999
 },
 {
  _id: c2,
  start: 1663322400000,
  finish: 1663329599999
 }
]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query and update the specific object with:

```
const updated = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'confirmedBookings._id': c1 },
  {
    'confirmedBookings.$.start': 'new-start',
    'confirmedBookings.$.finish': 'new-finish',
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **elemMatch** to find the element inside an array, and then update its value.

```js
return await documentName.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 
      confirmedBookings: { $elemMatch: { _id: "c1"} } 
   }, 
   {
      "confirmedBookings.$": newValue
   }
);
```

Write your schema's name to documentName.

Also, write your value to search as `$elemMatch: {_id: "c1"}`. The newValue is the new value you want to update.

Hope, it's helpful and clear